# Checking for increments in PHP

Tags: php

Using PHP, if I have a starting value, how can I check to see if another value is within a certain number of increments away?

In other words if I start with the value 100 and have an increment of 5, then 90, 95, 105, 110 would all be acceptable, but 104 would not.

Comment: Well, what about you test with conditions?

Comment: The above comment was meant to show how vague the question is and that it does not make much sense to invest into an answer... Voting to close...

Comment: calculate its % to 5 , it must equal to 0

Comment: what if the starting number was 98? then 93, 103, 108, etc. would be acceptable, right? In order to use the code sample in Thomas's answer, the numbers in the calculations would likely need to be adjusted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($number %5 == 0) {
  //CODE
}
```

This gets the remainder of `$number/5`. If it equals 0 then obviously it is divisible by 5 and thus is in your sequence.

Comment: This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to take the mod of the inputted number and compare it to the mod of the other number and see if they are the same. For example if you start with 99,

```
99 % 5 == 4
```

so now you can see all the increments by checking the mod of them in comparison.

```
104 % 5 == 4
109 % 5 == 4
```

So store the mod of the input number vs the mod number and then check to see if it is the same as the mod of the new number. I would write you a php example, but I don't use php.